# What is the equivalent of Preload from Ubuntu to Windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, memory, speed

Is there a software like Preload from Ubuntu, but for Windows 7? I can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SpeedUp way:

/1. Registry control system settings:

Speedup.cmd:

```
@SET uint=/t REG_DWORD /d
@SET Control=HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control

::@SET stCmd=@echo
:: delete :: - see key, value

@SET stCmd=@echo reg add
:: delete :: - see command

::@SET stCmd=reg add
:: delete :: - patch registry

@SET Prefetch="%Control%\Session Manager\Memory Management\PrefetchParameters"
%stCmd% %Prefetch% /v EnablePrefetcher %uint% 5 /f
%stCmd% %Prefetch% /v EnableSuperfetch %uint% 3 /f

@SET FS="%Control%\FileSystem"
%stCmd% %FS% /v NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate %uint% 1 /f
%stCmd% %FS% /v NtfsMemoryUsage %uint% 2 /f

@SET Priority="%Control%\PriorityControl"
%stCmd% %Priority% /v Win32PrioritySeparation %uint% 2 /f
%stCmd% %Priority% /v IRQ8Priority %uint% 1 /f
%stCmd% %Priority% /v IRQ14Priority %uint% 1 /f
%stCmd% %Priority% /v IRQ15Priority %uint% 1 /f

@SET Memory="%Control%\Session Manager\Memory Management"
%stCmd% %Memory% /v DisablePagingExecutive %uint% 1 /f
%stCmd% %Memory% /v LargeSystemCache %uint% 1 /f
%stCmd% %Memory% /v IOPageLockLimit %uint% 0x04000000 /f

@SET RegExplorer="HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer"
%stCmd% %RegExplorer% %uint% 0 /f
```

/2. Memory and cache software:

[SuperCache Express™ 5 for Desktop Systems](http://www.superspeed.com/desktop/supercache.php)

[image: SuperCache Express™ 5 for Desktop Systems]

[Desktop Performance Solutions](http://www.superspeed.com/desktop/solutions.php)

[Product Suite / Servers](http://www.superspeed.com/servers/productsuite.php)

/3. Partition and file geometry set at HDD.

Swap file at first ... and more)

Symantec Speed Disk as sample.

/4. Virtualization:

It may seem strange. But in my experience there were cases where virtualization accelerates the work of certain systems several times.

may be help)

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 includes "prefetch" which will automatically manage and preload commonly used programs.  You do not need to do anything, it will manage itself.

[Here](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=windows%207%20prefetch) is a google search link.

Comment: I don't understand this exaggerated level of snobbishness in stackexhange. I googled "Windows 7 Preload". How on earth would you want me to guess to google "Windows 7 prefetch" If I've never seen the word "prefetch" in my life.

Comment: I gave that link because an actual Google link is around 300 characters.  "Snobbishness" was not intended, expediency was.